# Points on axis only half-shown

Tags: plotting

I need to add two points on a Plot. As they're on the axes, and `PlotRange->{{0,27},{0,27}}` only half the points are shown. I don't want to increase the `PlotRange` to include negative values, and I'd rather not have the axes extending below `(0,0)`.

Is there any other option? My code is the following:

**Edited full code**

```
Plot[
 {Piecewise[{
    {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9},
    {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 25}}],
  Piecewise[{
    {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9},
    {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 30}}],
  25 - q}, {q, 0, 30},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 27}},
 PlotRangePadding -> .5,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Exclusions -> None,
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Black, Dashed], 
   Directive[Black, Thickness[.005]]},
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 12},
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick],
 Ticks -> None,
 AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[q, HoldForm[A]]], 
   HoldForm[Subscript[q, HoldForm[B]]]},
 Epilog -> {
   Text[HoldForm[L] == 50, {8, 25}],
   Text[HoldForm[K] == 50, {22, 8}],
   Text[HoldForm[q] == 25, {5, 22}],
   Text[HoldForm[R], {25, 1}],
   Text[HoldForm[S], {1, 25}],
   PointSize -> .025,
   Point[{{25, 0}, {0, 25}}]
```

}
]

Comment: Add the option `PlotRangePadding -> 0.5`

Comment: @BobHanlon But with `PlotRangePadding` the axes go below 0. In this sense, it's equivalent to increase the `PlotRange`. Isn't it possible to have the axes to start at `(0,0)` and the points to show entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) and [`PlotRangeClipping`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html):

```
Plot[
 {Piecewise[{{(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, 
     100/9 < q < 25}}], 
  Piecewise[{{(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 
     100/9 < q < 30}}], 25 - q}, {q, 0, 27},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 27}},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Exclusions -> None,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
 Ticks -> None,
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> .025, Point[{{25, 0}, {0, 25}}]},
 ImagePadding -> 20,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False
 ]
```

[image]

This works by first expanding the white-space around the plot area, and then making sure that objects are not clipped at the edge of the plot range. Note that I have change the range for `q` to go only to 27, so that the lines end where the axis ends (otherwise, the lines will go over the axis label)

Comment: But it does clip the `AxesLabel` (I didn't include them in my original question, sorry).

Comment: You just need to increase the `ImagePadding` (see edited answer) - note that you can specify different values for different sides if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) to plot the points and then combine the two plots using [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{{25, 0}, {0, 25}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.025]}, AspectRatio -> 1, Ticks -> None], 
 Plot[{Piecewise[{{(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 25}}], 
   Piecewise[{{(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 30}}], 25 - q}, {q, 0, 30}, Exclusions -> None, 
   Filling -> {1 -> Axis}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want part of the axes to show, draw them manually:

```
Plot[{
  Piecewise[{{(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, 
     100/9 < q < 25}}],
  Piecewise[{{(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 
     100/9 < q < 30}}], 25 - q}, {q, 0, 30},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 27}},
 PlotRangePadding -> 0.5,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Exclusions -> None,
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
 Axes -> None,
 Prolog -> {Lighter[Gray, 0.5], Line[{{0, 27}, {0, 0}, {27, 0}}]},
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize -> .025, Point[{{25, 0}, {0, 25}}]}]
```

[image]

If you are manually adding the axes, you must also manually add the axes labels.

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 
     q <= 100/9}, {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 25}}], 
  Piecewise[{{(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 
     100/9 < q < 30}}], 25 - q}, {q, 0, 27}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 27}}, PlotRangePadding -> 2,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Exclusions -> None,
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
 Axes -> None,
 Prolog -> {
   Text[Style["x", Italic, 12], {27, 0}, {-3, 0}], 
   Text[Style["y", Italic, 12], {0, 27}, {0, -1.5}],
   Lighter[Gray, 0.5],
   Line[{{0, 27}, {0, 0}, {27, 0}}]},
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> .025, Point[{{25, 0}, {0, 25}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: If I set `Axes->None` then I cannot use `AxesLabel`

Comment: As you change or clarify what you are looking for, edit your question to reflect the requirements. People do not want to read through all of the comments to find out what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. Just did it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` option. Like so:

```
Plot[
  {Piecewise[{{(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 25}}], 
   Piecewise[{{(10 - 2*q^(1/2))^2, q <= 100/9}, {(5 - .5*q^(1/2))^2, 100/9 < q < 30}}], 25 - q}, {q, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 27}, {0, 27}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02],
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Exclusions -> None,
  Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
  Ticks -> None,
  Epilog -> {PointSize -> .025, Point[{{25, 0}, {0, 25}}]}]
```

[image: plot]